# spring-mvc: split logic what is the best practice

Tags: spring-mvc

i am a newler in spring, I would like to implement the following idea, but i don't know whether it works or what to do to make it correct.

So i.e. the workflow is:

1. to send an email
2. to store it in database

I have a controller with two methods. The method "sendEmail" works fine and i have to do something to call the method "storeHistory". I would like to implement this idea academically beautiful (accordance to the best practice).

```js
 @RequestMapping(value={"/sendEmail"}, method=POST)
 public String sendEmail(EmailDispatchForm form,Model model ){
  String status = "OK";
  Email domainEmail = emailAdapter.convertEmailFormToServiceEmail(form) ;

  logger.debug(form);
  logger.debug(domainEmail);
  
  try {
   emailSendService.sendEmail(domainEmail);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   status = "ERROR";
   model.addAttribute("errDescription", e.getCause().getMessage());
   logger.error(e, e);
  }finally {
   model.addAttribute("sentEmailStatus", status);
  }
  
  return "email_sent_form";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value={"/storeHistory"}, method=POST)
 public void storeHistory(EmailDispatchForm form, Model model){
  EMail historyEmail = emailAdapter.convertEmailFormToDomainEmail(form);
  logger.debug(historyEmail);
  dataProvider.storeEmailForHistory(historyEmail);
  
 }
```

Sure i can do it in one method, but i would like to split the logic in two different methods.

How would you do it?
Perhaps something like "redirect:storeHistory", but i am not sure it is a well idea, so i have now idea.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I think what you have unnecessarily muddies the controller, as you described both of your existing controller methods as being part of the same workflow.
I think the best approach is for the controller to be wired to a single service layer method which both sends the email, and then stores the history.  You can certainly then have that service layer call into a couple of private methods (to send the email, to save the history) and of course more gracefully address the concern of what happens if the email isn't sent for some reason (which should result in *not* writing the history?).